# What if i want to use web-renderer canvaskit and html both, as my project dependent on both rendering

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

My project's lots of features depend on web-renderer html but one feature of showing text markers on Google Maps is dependent on a web-renderer canvas kit, is there a way I can use both rendering in my project. i have tried with --web-renderer auto also doesn't work for me.

Image 1 - Using canvas kit markers are being loaded correctly but images are not loading.

Image 2 - Using HTML due to markers not loading but images are.

(Images are getting fetched from multiple provider locations so it's giving some cors or loading issue error so I can enable cors policy from my server but this issue is getting resolved using HTML rendering, so I need to use HTML)[Image1[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8i8m.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHVOg.jpg)

I want to achieve both image and marker rendering should work.

This createCustomMarkerBitmap is being use to create marker on map

```html
Future<BitmapDescriptor> createCustomMarkerBitmap(String title,
    {required TextStyle textStyle,
    Color backgroundColor = Colors.blueAccent}) async {
  TextSpan span = TextSpan(
    style: textStyle,
    text: title,
  );
  TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
    text: span,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
  );
  painter.text = TextSpan(
    text: title.toString(),
    style: textStyle,
  );
  ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
  painter.layout();
  painter.paint(canvas, const Offset(20.0, 10.0));
  int textWidth = painter.width.toInt();
  int textHeight = painter.height.toInt();
  canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(0, 0, textWidth + 40, textHeight + 20,
          bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(10),
          bottomRight: const Radius.circular(10),
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(10)),
      Paint()..color = backgroundColor);
  var arrowPath = Path();
  arrowPath.moveTo((textWidth + 40) / 2 - 15, textHeight + 20);
  arrowPath.lineTo((textWidth + 40) / 2, textHeight + 40);
  arrowPath.lineTo((textWidth + 40) / 2 + 15, textHeight + 20);
  arrowPath.close();
  canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, Paint()..color = backgroundColor);
  painter.layout();
  painter.paint(canvas, const Offset(20.0, 10.0));
  ui.Picture p = pictureRecorder.endRecording();
  ByteData? pngBytes = await (await p.toImage(
          painter.width.toInt() + 40, painter.height.toInt() + 50))
      .toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List data = Uint8List.view(pngBytes!.buffer);
  return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data);
}
```

Code to load the image which is getting fail with the canvaskit but when I am using image_network then its only able to load 5-10 images for more images its stuck-

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: (context, imageUrl) => SizedBox(
          width: imageWidth,
          height: imageHeight,
          child: Container(
            width: imageWidth,
            height: imageHeight,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                  AppColors.termAndPolicyColor),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        errorWidget: (context, imageUrl, error) => Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.image,
            size:
                imageHeight, // Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? 200.sp : 100.sp,
            color: AppColors.orangeTextColor.withOpacity(0.8),
          ),
        ),
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
          width: imageWidth,
          height: imageHeight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: boxShape,
            image: DecorationImage(image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
      )
```

Comment: can you share some code where you use the image to load from an url

Comment: @dstreissi please check I have updated the question with the code.